# Google map api get key "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers"

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

If i want to use only on local first ,what should i add sir,i m testing the google map.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave it blank for now. The field is optional.

Answer (score 4):

If you leave this blank, then google sends the data to wherever the requests come. Later if the application is online, you should put your the website address there, so Google will send the data to only your application. Otherwise other people could use the key.

Comment: did you find a solution?